# I can not show the $scope data inside my Paragraph tag

Tags: angularjs

which part of my code is wrong ??
if it has a lot of error please don't give me UNLIKE :D im so new in Angularjs

```
<script>
demoapp = angular.module('demoapp', []);
demoapp.factory('simplefactory', function ($scope) {
    //var customers = [{ name: 'Alireza', family: 'massali' }, { name: 'Ehsan', family: 'abdolahi' }, { name: 'Ali', family: 'Shirvanian'}];
    var customers ="3576324";
    //var factory = {};
    this.GetCust = function () {
       return customers;
    };


    this.PostCust = function (customer) {
        return customers;
    };
    return factory;
});



var xxx = angular.module('mmodule', []);
var conts = {}
conts.simple = function ($scope, simplefactory) {
    $scope.name = simplefactory.GetCust();
}

conts.simple1 = function ($scope) {
    $scope.name1 = "2222";
}

xxx.controller(conts);
```

and here is the HTML

```
<div ng-app='mmodule'>
<p ng-controller='simple'>{{name}}</p></div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ?!

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Your call `xxx.controller(conts)` seems weird, since your passing a hash (or did something recently change in the Angular API that I missed out on?).  Have you tried registering the controller(s) with the usual `xxx.controller("simple", function(...){...})` instead?  See also http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module

Comment: can you put this in live editor and give us a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can try to get you started on the right lines.
You appear to be using 2 modules, which I assume you have some reason to do.
The 'mmodule' module is attempting to use the factory defined in the 'demoapp' module. But it doesn't know where it is. So the first thing you need to do is inject the 'demoapp' module into the 'mmodule'.
So you need to change the line var xxx=angular.module.... to

```
var xxx=angular.module('mmodule', ['demoapp']);
```

Now the functions defined in your factory should become available.

The way you have set up your factory is different to the way that I set up mine. I would use:

```
 demoapp.factory('simplefactory', function () {

   var customers ="3576324";
   //var factory = {};
    return{
     GetCust: function () {
       return customers;
     },


     PostCust: function (customer) {
       return customers;
     }
  };
});
```

There is a plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/WisW6f?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not correct. In your factory, you are returning `factory`, which is not defined. If you want to use `GetCust` and the other functions you must return `this`.

Answer (score 1):

What you require is this:

```
demoapp = angular.module('demoapp', []);
demoapp.factory('simplefactory', function () {
```

Factory doesn't take in scope

```
    var customers = "3576324";

    return {
        GetCust: function () {
            return customers;
        },


        PostCust: function (customer) {
            return customers;
        }
    }
```

You need to return an object containing your functions

```
});



var xxx = angular.module('mmodule', ['demoapp']);
```

Most importantly inject the demoapp module in this one...

```
var conts = {}
conts.simple = function ($scope, simplefactory) {
    $scope.name = simplefactory.GetCust();
}

conts.simple1 = function ($scope) {
    $scope.name1 = "2222";
}

xxx.controller(conts);
```